# R - Add trace in Plotly if condition is met

Tags: r, plotly

I am creating a scatter plot graph and I would like the points connected by a trace if a condition is met. My data is separated into sequences, if an X and Y coordinate is part of the same sequence, I would like there to be a trace. My sample data and code snippet is below.

Sample Data:

```
X   Y   Seq
1   3    1
2   5    1
1   4    1
3   1    2
4   5    2
6   3    3
3   4    3
```

In this example I would like points (1, 3), (2, 5), (1, 4) traced, points (3, 1), (4, 5) traced, and points (6, 3), (3, 4) traced. There should be a break in the trace if a new sequence starts.

Code:

```
 plot_ly (data, x = data$X , y = data$Y,
          type = "scatter", 
          mode="markers")%>%
          add_trace(data$Seq==shift(data$Seq, type="lag"), mode="lines")
```

Here is an image of the plot that my actual data is giving me. You can see the points are being plotted but there is no break.[image: Trace]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your use of `add_trace`.  You're passing what I assume is a subset of your data to the first argument of `add_trace` when this argument expects an existing plot/trace. The problem is, since you're piping in with `%>%` the function is inheriting the original data and ignoring your subset.

Note that the below will give the same plot even though my variable `NO` has nothing to do with the plot:

```
X=c(1,2,1,3,4,6,3)
Y=c(3,5,4,1,5,3,4)
seq=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
dataX <- data.frame(X,Y,seq)

NO <- "this won't work"
plot_ly plot_ly (dataX, x = dataX$X , y = dataX$Y,
         type = "scatter", 
         mode="markers") %>%
          add_trace(NO, mode="lines")
```

[image]

You can fix this with `inherit=F`, but then it won't work because `add_trace` is trying to add something to the plot `NO` which isn't a plot (and your subset wouldn't work either)

```
plot_ly (dataX, x = dataX$X , y = dataX$Y,
         type = "scatter", 
         mode="markers") %>%
  add_trace(NO, mode="lines", inherit=FALSE)

## No trace type specified:
```

When you add traces you want to be explicit in the `x=` and `y=`. Then you can allow it to automatically inherit the previous plot/trace, or specify one. As for what you're trying to do, you could build it up with a loop:

```
#make the plot
p <- plot_ly (dataX, x = dataX$X , y = dataX$Y,
         type = "scatter", 
         mode="markers")

#build it up
for(i in levels(factor(dataX$seq))){
  #subset data
  dataFilt <- dataX[dataX$seq==i,]
  #add it
  p <- add_trace(p, x=dataFilt$X, y=dataFilt$Y,mode="lines",color ='yellow')
}
p
```

[image]

This makes a new series each time so it's a bit of a work around. You can hide the legend and it looks correct:

```
p %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]